# My AWS EC2 Ubuntu server uses 1.25x the memory, but is twice as slow. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I made myself a speedtest. It's the following:

```
const CryptoJs = require('crypto-js')
const fs = require('fs')

var start = Date.now()

async function yeah(wait, counter){


    if (counter == 1){
        console.log(Date.now()-start)

    }
}

words = CryptoJs.AES.encrypt('files', 'hi').toString()

for (let i = 1000000000; i > 0; i--){
    yeah(words, i)
}
```

On my own computer, it takes about 9.4 seconds to execute, but on my aws server, it takes anywhere from 18 to 26 seconds. Using pm2, I can see that on AWS, it is using 46mb, and on my home computer, it is using only 38mb.

Why is it so slow on AWS, and what can I do to make it faster?

Comment: If you want it to run faster, use a faster instance.

Comment: Speed depends on instance type. Maybe your computer is faster than the AWS instance you've chosen.

Comment: I wouldn't stress about slight differences in memory footprint. That could be caused by OS factors beyond your control, or slightly different versions of Node.

Comment: Share your laptop spec and instance spec otherwise we do not know what these numbers mean.